# Is it possible to get the ATR value of Point and figure charts?

Tags: pine-script

I programmed an indicator that compute the goals of price of a point and figure chart.

I use a point and figure chart with the size of the box computed using the ATR with a length of 14.
I would like to know if I can get the value of the ATR computed to draw the point and figure chart to use it in my computations.

I tried to find the info in the ticker of the point and figure chart but it is not available.

Currently, I have to enter manually the value of the ATR as an input every time I changed of crypto or symbol.

Thanks a lot for the help.